# Resize text + image in proportion to nav bar when zooming

Tags: html, css

When I zoom my website the logo and text tend to not resize with the same proportionals as the div itself. The div is set up with % in the css to appear as the same size all the time. How do I make them resize equal when zooming?

I've tried to set the font size in `%`, but that doesn't work. The image is already the perfect size so I haven't resized that in the css.

[Live example on the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joyzc132/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id=nav>
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="50.png">
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Spotlight</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>           
            <li><a href="#">What is ?</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#logo{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: -2px;
}
#nav{
    height: 7%;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-color: #02ddfe;
}
#menu{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    position: fixed;
    left: 2%;
    font-size: 100%;
    top: -2%;
}
#menu ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 47px; 
    position: absolute;
}
#menu ul ul{
    display: none;
}
#menu ul a{
    color: #bbbbbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.4s;
    transition: color 0.4s;
}
#menu ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu ul li a,visited{
    color: #bbbbbb;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul li a:hover{
    color: #4ebbe8;
    text-decoration: none;
}    
#menu ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
#menu ul ul{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: pls share your fiddle code

Answer (score 0):

try this one : http://jsfiddle.net/rfv2h3m5/1/

code change : 
HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Spotlight</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>           
        <li><a href="#">What is ?</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
#logo{
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    background:url("http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/pnggrad8rgb.png") no-repeat;
    width:8%;
    height:72%;
    background-size: 100%;
}
#nav{
    height: 40%;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-color: #02ddfe;
    font-size : 100%;
}
#menu{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    position: fixed;
    left: 2%;
    font-size: 100%;
    top: -2%;
}
#menu ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
#menu ul ul{
    display: none;
}
#menu ul a{
    color: #bbbbbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.4s;
    transition: color 0.4s;
}
#menu ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

#menu ul li a,visited{
    color: #bbbbbb;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul li a:hover{
    color: #4ebbe8;
    text-decoration: none;
}    
#menu ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
#menu ul ul{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```